# phonegap-googlemaps-plugin + $ionicPopup

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing one aplication with [IonicFramework](http://ionicframework.com/) with [phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin) that, when the user clicks on the infoWindow's marker, it calls an confirm function, then calls [launchNavigation](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/External-Service) if *true*.

My problem is, if i use the native **confirm** function it works great, but when i'm trying to use **[$ionicPopup.confirm({})](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)** i can not click on the confirm's buttons. Looks like i keep clicking on the map.

I already tried to change the z-index property of the class '*popup-containe*', but seems not to work the way i expected.

```
    data.map(function (m) {

        var latLng = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng)
        latLngs.push(latLng);

        map.addMarker({
            position: latLng,
            title: m.placa,
            snippet: 'Clique para ir nessa localização.',
            styles : {
                'text-align': 'center',
                'font-weight': 'bold'
            }
        }, function (marker) {

            marker.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.INFO_CLICK, function(marker) {

                var confirm = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: m.placa,
                    template: 'Abrir navegação para essa localização?',
                    okText: 'Sim',
                    cancelText: 'Não'
                })

                document.getElementsByClassName('popup-container')[0].style.zIndez = 999999;

                confirm.then(function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        map.getMyLocation(function (location) {
                            mobileLocation = location.latLng;

                            marker.getPosition(function(markerLocation) {

                                plugin.google.maps.external.launchNavigation({
                                    'from': mobileLocation,
                                    'to': markerLocation
                                });

                            })
                        })
                    }
                })

                $timeout(function() {
                    confirm.close();
                }, 3000);

                /*
                if (confirm("Abrir direção para " + m.placa)) {
                    map.getMyLocation(function(location) {
                        mobileLocation = location.latLng;

                        marker.getPosition(function (markerLocation) {

                            plugin.google.maps.external.launchNavigation({
                                "from": mobileLocation,
                                "to": markerLocation
                            });

                        });

                    });
                }
                */
            });
        });
    });
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try  `$scope.confirm` instead of `var confirm`.

Comment: @mudasserajaz did not work. This way, not even the close on timeout work here. idk why.

Answer (score -1):

Simple is that you just set

`map.setClickable(false)` when show `$ionicPopup` then after `map.setClickable(true).`

Works perfect.